# pointers and segmentation faults in C?

Tags: c

I'm new to C so please correct anything in this question, and also I might be too vague in my question as well.  I have code that kind of goes like this, and I'm getting a segmentation fault.  I read online that segmentation faults happen usually when u access a pointer that points to nothing

```
struct apple get(char* name) {
    struct apple a;
    a.name = name;
    return a;
}
struct apple* read(){
    struct apple* ap = (struct apple*)malloc(2*sizeof(struct apple));
    ap[0] = get("bob");
    return ap;
}

// loop through in another function which reads a pointer to an
// apple object in the array and then accesses apple->name
```

when it accesses apple->name there is a segmentation fault.  I am assuming this is because the apple object was declared as a local variable and its freed later by c??? I really have no idea why I get a segmentation fault or how to fix it or how c works with freeing structs that were initialized as a local variable in a function. Can someone please tell me what's going on, thanks!

Comment: Where exactly do you get the error? There is no line saying apple->name in your example code.

Comment: I think you will need to provide a bit more context - how is apple defined, and how exactly are you using these functions?  Anyway, [valgrind](http://valgrind.org) can be very helpful for finding the source of memory issues like this.

Comment: It doesn't help much to tell us your code "kind of goes like this".  There's nothing in the code you showed us that should cause a segmentation fault.  Show us a small complete program that exhibits the problem.  `get()` returns a struct *by value*, so there's no problem there.  `read()` returns a pointer to heap-allocated memory; that pointer will be valid until you `free()` it explicitly.

Comment: A more idiomatic and robust way to declare `ap` is `struct apple *ap = malloc(2 * sizeof *ap);`.  And you should always check whether the allocation succeeded (if it fails, `ap == NULL`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, segmentation fault errors happen when the pointer points to something *wrong*, not necessarily when the pointer is *empty*.

There is nothing wrong in the code snippet that you posted: `"bob"` is a `char*` that stays valid for the life of the program, and the return of `apple` is done by value, so you are not returning a pointer to a local either. The issue is most likely in the code that iterates over apples returned from `read()`.

Comment: Are you sure that "bob" stays valid for the whole program, not just during the read() function? Anyway, I'm surprised that get("bob") even compiles, since "bob" is a const char* and get() takes a char*. But that could be just me.

Comment: String literals are valid for the whole program. (they allocated in the DATA section). If I remember it correctly, they are not const.

Comment: I am reasonably certain that string constants are allocated in the same segment as the binary code, so yes, they stay around for the lifetime of your program. Passing `const char*` to `char*` does not trigger a warning in C (I verified it in gcc).

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with reading `ap[0].name` later on (where `ap` is the pointer returned by `read()`).

On the other hand, reading `ap[1].name` is undefined behaviour since you've never initialized it.

Also, modifying the string pointed to by `ap[0].name` is not allowed since it points to a string literal.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you try to change the string. In C, string literals supposed to be read-only, and trying to change them is undefined behavior. If you want a.name to not be read-only, you can use strdup. (and don't forget to free it)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not very experience with C myself, but I can take a shot at answering it at the risk of being heavily downvoted..

I think the problem is that you are allocating the memory on the heap in the wrong place. As far I understand, your intention is that `get` returns an new `apple` struct with the supplied name? In that case you should allocate the memory in the `get` method and then return a `struct apple *` instead. So something *like*:

```
struct apple *get(char* name) {
    struct apple *ap = (struct apple *) malloc(sizeof(struct apple));
    ap->name = name;
    return ap;
}
```

Comment: It's completely legal to return a struct (but it's not recomended).
The return value is a copy of the local variable. (exactly as if it was an int, for example).